# When combining nginx with expressJS, shall I use compression in express or nginx?

Tags: express, nginx, compression

I have an app running on nodeJS/express and also using nginx. If I compress the served files on both systems, I suppose that slows the server response time. Therefore, when combining nginx with expressJS, do you use [compression in express](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/compression.html) or [compression in nginx](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/compression/)? Or it simply doesn't matter!?

I know it may be opinion based, but I really wanted some feedback on this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NGINX supports also somewhat superior Brotli compression (aside from gzip), via [3rd party module](https://github.com/google/ngx_brotli).
So having all compression done in NGINX makes more sense.

TTFB should not be affected if you keep both (NGINX will figure out that the response is already compressed). But for that same reason (NGINX receiving an already compressed response), you won't be able to add Brotli compression support to it (if you keep it in expressJS), because the Brotli compression module expects an uncompressed response to work with.

Comment: so would you recommend me to turn off express compression if I have already gzip compression in nginx?

Comment: Yes, sure. Since NGINX is very efficient and C-based app, it can do compression faster. See [here](https://expressjs.com/en/advanced/best-practice-performance.html#use-gzip-compression) as well. "For a high-traffic website in production, the best way to put compression in place is to implement it at a reverse proxy level (see Use a reverse proxy). In that case, you do not need to use compression middleware. For details on enabling gzip compression in Nginx..." They recommend the same :)

Comment: Just to give some feedback, the simplest solution that gave me the best performance was to keep compression in nginx turned on (I didn't touch the configuration files), and activate the fastest compression in node middleware with `app.use(compression({ level: 1 }))`, as level 1 is for the fastest compression. Since nginx will figure out that the response is already compressed, nginx does not lose time processing it.

Comment: I could certainly also change the compression rate/speed in nginx, but this was simpler to do.